# ArangoDB batch insert of edges without user defined keys

Tags: bulkinsert, arangodb

Is it possible to batch insert edges into arangodb without user defined keys, but a uniquely indexed attribute?

For example (in pseudo code):

```
from db.C.name=x to db.D.number=y
```

Where both name and number have unique indexes, but defining user-originated keys would be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of an edge index is to link vertex documents, which are defined by their `_id` attribute (e.g. `collection/key`).  Because of the way the engine works, you ***must*** provide a `_from` and `_to` attribute with each edge...

...but that doesn't stop you from adding your own attributes (and indexing them)!

Because of the [unique nature of edge indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558463/arangodb-index-usage-with-edge-collections), I was forced to add my own `from_id` and `to_id` values, which mirrored the `_from` and `_to`, respectively.  Adding a hash index to these allowed me to quickly reconcile new, existing, and obsolete records.

Alternatively, it might be possible to use the `name` and `number` values as `_key` values.  Nothing says you ***need*** to use the system-supplied `_key`.  The only caveat is the `_key` and `_id` values have [character restrictions](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/DataModeling/NamingConventions/DocumentKeys.html).

Comment: yeah, wound up just rebuilding the database.  Using a unique indexer is computationally equivalent (in terms of theory), but I guess simplicity of the engine is better.